# Could someone please share the Matlab code for the stochastic volatility jump diffusion option pricing model? (Bates model)

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-volatility, jump, bates

I have not been able to write a Matlab code for the Bates model without errors. Could someone share theirs please?

Comment: Don't give up!  Fix the problems in your code until it works!

Comment: At least, don't expect others to give you the code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code requests are not appreciated.